# Python Cryptogrophy module with CA, -ext and -config options

Tags: python, openssl, python-cryptography

I need to recreate this openssl command line in python and have been requested to use the cryptography module. It makes use of an extensions file and a configuration file as well as using CA (not X509):

```
OPENSSL ca -extfile my_extfile.ext -config my_openssl.cnf -startdate $start_date -days $duration -md sha256 -cert $signing_ca -key $pk -in $csr -out $cert -batch
```

I haven't actually found any documentation on using CA with pyca/cryptography (only X509), or for that matter any way to specify the ext and config files with cryptography either.

I looked at pyOpenSSL which stated 'If you are using pyOpenSSL for anything other than making a TLS connection you should move to cryptography and drop your pyOpenSSL dependency'. This implies that I should be able to run my command using cryptography but I'm having a hard time trying to work out how to do it so any help is welcomed.

Thanks,
Matt.

Comment: You don't want to use `-ext` or `-config` to parse OpenSSL configuration, you want to learn how to use the Cryptography APIs to create the certificate authority and certificate without using OpenSSL.  Have a look at the certificate tutorial here: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/tutorial/#creating-a-self-signed-certificate and go from the APIs referenced from there.  Comment rather than an answer because I have no idea how to answer your actual question here :-).

Answer (score 2):

`cryptography` is not a different frontend to OpenSSL's CLI commands. It is its own API with the ability to use OpenSSL (the library, not the CLI `openssl`) to perform cryptographic operations. The `cryptography` X.509 documentation contains information and examples sufficient to create X.509 certificates, CRLs, CSRs, and even OCSP request/response objects, but a developer needs to convert from an OpenSSL config file into the different programming environment offered by those APIs.

Your question strongly suggests a basic misunderstanding about what these libraries are and how they work. You may need to go back to whoever requested this and work with them to establish what your current infrastructure does and how to replicate it most effectively using `cryptography` or any other language/library.